# How to make a script persistent/crash-resistant in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, crash, persistence

Say I have a very simple script like

**(basic script)**

```
function f() {
  console.log("step 1");
  console.log("step 2");
  console.log("step 3");
}
```

Unfortunately, the environment in which this script runs is very prone to several types of crashes, e.g. power shortages. In case of a crash, `f()` is called again by a supervising program. So in that case, I could for instance get the following output:

**(actual output)**

```
step 1
step 2
// crash occurs here, the supervisor restarts the program and calls f() again
step 1
step 2
step 3
```

But what I actually want is that crashes do not influence the program, that is the expected result

**(desired output)**

```
step 1
step 2
// crash occurs here, the supervisor restarts the program and calls f() again
// ...but "at the right position"!
step 3
```

Is there a way to achieve this? The only way I could imagine was to store the current state of `f` persistently in a file that is read when `f` is called. However, that would look like this:

**(my approach)**

```
function f() {
  const state = loadState(); // e.g., 2
  if (state <= 1) {
    console.log("step 1");
    storeState(++state);
  }
  if (state <= 2) {
    console.log("step 2");
    storeState(++state);
  }
  if (state <= 3) {
    console.log("step 3");
    storeState(++state);
  }
}
```

That gets me what I want but it is obviously very tedious and makes the program completely unreadable in a real-world example.

So, **is there a better solution**? Maybe even a standard solution for such problems that I am not aware of? One would think that there could be a possiblity that the complete "Node state" is stored or similar. (Note that crashes like power shortages can probably not be caught by software, so that the persistence logic would need to be executed during the normal script run.)

Answer (score 0):

Your approch is the easiest. adapted to a sequence of actions.

if you want to be more free with the flow you can use a message broker. (here is a simplified version of CQRS)
it can easily allow you to continue to step 2 if some conditions are met in step3 for exemple.

i would do this :

```
function executeTask(task) {
  if (task.step == 1) {
    // do some work and create next task
    sendTasktoBroken({step: 2, ...})
  }
  else if (task.step == 2) {
    // do some work and create next task
    sendTasktoBroken({step: 3, ...})
  }
  else if (task.step == 3) {
    // do some work and create the final task
    sendTasktoBroken({step: 4, message: 'all done with success'})
  }
}

function sendTasktoBroken(task) {
}

let task = getOneTaskFromBroker()
executetask(task);
```

the broker can be redis or a socketio service or a simple event listener.